# multiple conditions to create a computed column

Tags: sql, sas

I want to create a computed column in SAS enterprise guide where it’ll show car items if it meets certain conditions. There are 75 car items (T.TS_Items) such as windscreen, tyres, steering wheel etc. Each item has a unique ID (T.TS_NUM) so T.TS_NUM =1 to T.TS_NUM =75. And I want to then give each new car item a label such as labelNo_01 to labelNo_75.
So if the vehicle type is Honda (T.TS_F_NUM = 2), type is Japanese (T.TS_TYPE = I) and  T.TS_NUM =1 then the new column name is LabelName_01  with a item  such as windscreen.
And if the vehicle type is Toyota (T.TS_F_NUM = 1) but the rest is the same it will give me the 75 car item for Toyota.

The above is very simple and works but I am not sure how to add an Else statement if the vehicle type is Toyota (T.TS_F_NUM = 1)

Also a loop would help so I dont have to repeat the process for each vehicle type. Hope this information helps.

Comment: This and your previous question are quite difficult to understand. Take a few minutes, and think carefully about what exactly you want. Then, try to explain as clearly as you can what you are trying to accomplish. It's helpful if you give an example of what your data look like, and what you want the results to look like. You could spend a few minutes looking at other `SAS` questions to see what a good question looks like. Also, if this is a homework problem, you should add "homework" as a tag.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
Select TS_TYPE from (
    SELECT T.TS_TYPE,
    CASE T._vehicle_type = 'honda' THEN 2
       ELSE 1 
    as TS_F_NUM_Val,
    CASE TSI.TSI_DESC = 'damaged' THEN 'Not Allocated'
      ELSE TSI.TSI_DESC 
    as TSI_DESC_Val
    WHERE T.TS_TYPE = I
    AND TS_F_NUM_val=T.TS_F_NUM
    AND TSI_DESC _val=TSI.TSI_DESC 
)
```

So that you get the columns you need, and can have a condition.

Comment: Thanks @david. I want to create a new column based on these conditions so need to used them all but I am not sure of the order. I tried this but its not giving me what I want. Anyothing else?

Comment: @Beanie See Itzy's comment on your question above.  Give an example of the data that you have, and what you would like the output to look like.

Comment: @RobPenridge, I have added some more data and information, hopefully its useful.